# Posting JSON with curl to Grails JSON REST API plugin

Tags: json, grails

I have a Grails app running on 1.3.7 with the json-rest-api plugin version 1.0.8 installed. I'm trying to post data from the command line using curl in order to create a new instance of a domain class, but cannot seem to figure out the correct way to format the JSON so that the parser is satisfied. I can't find any documentation either that would conclusively describe how the data is supposed to be formatted.

The domain class is defined like this:

```
package foo

class Foo {
  static expose = 'foo'

  String name

  static constraints = {
    name(inList: ['xyzzy', 'quux'])
  }
}
```

Given the above, this doesn't work:

```
$ curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-urlencode '{"name":"xyzzy"}' http://myapp/api/foo
```

The app returns a 500 error code and the content of the reply is

```
{"success":false,"message":"Property [name] of class [class foo.Foo] cannot be null"}
```

What kind of data does the API expect me to send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following format:

```
{ data: { name: "Blabla" } }
```

Comment: You can always peek at the format sent by ExtJS'es JsonStore. This plugin is designed to work exactly with this client in mind.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, you set me on the right track! I thought I had already tried every combo but this did it, **when combined** with dropping curl's URL encoding and using just `--data "..."` to send the JSON over.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't specific to the json-rest API.  I've only ever used the built in RESTful capabilities of Grails.

You need your URL Mapping so that parseRequest = true.  You have to include the class in your JSON:

```
{"class":"Foo", "name":"blabla"}
```

In your controller, you do this...

```
def fooInstance = new Foo(params['foo'])
```

And your gold.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My problem does however seem to be specific to this particular plugin, because the [mappings are automatically provided by the plugin](https://github.com/padcom/grails-json-rest-api/blob/master/grails-app/conf/JsonRestApiUrlMappings.groovy). Bizarrely it **doesn't** specify `parseRequest=true` though. It does seem like it should work somehow, so maybe this is not the root cause after all?

Comment: What are you getting out of the plugin that Grails doesn't give you out the box?

Comment: Good question. I couldn't tell you though as I didn't write the app, I'm just trying to use it. Reading the [short plugin description](http://www.grails.org/plugin/json-rest-api), what I **should** be getting is near-zero-config POST to create functionality. If I can get that otherwise, I can spend an hour or two tearing out the plugin and using another method, if I get some good pointers :)

Comment: Well, glancing over the plugin it looks like it is doing automatic URL Mapping (which is funny because for our project, we also used /api/whatever) and automatic JSON rendering from the Domain.  The downside to the plugin is that it doesn't look like you get much control over the returned data.  I don't like sending payloads with useless data.  So I like being in total control of what is getting rendered to the client.

Comment: So if you're willing to create your own URL Mappings and render your own JSON, then I don't see much of a difference.  But take that with a grain of salt. I have zero knowledge of your project and I don't want to start you on a wrong path.  Do your research over what Grails provides out of the box before you just take my word for it.